# Parameters to constructor in autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have to gridviews on screen 1 and 2

```
builder.RegisterInstance(dataGridView1)
builder.RegisterInstance(dataGridView2)
builder.RegisterType<GeneralHtmlNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
```

How do i tell in the class that i the constructor that i want named datagridview1 and not datagridview2 if register a instance

```
public GeneralHtmlNotifier(DataGridView dataGridView1, IEnumerable<IChecker> checkers)
{
    _clsDataGridView = dataGridView1;
    _checkers = checkers;
}
```

Comment: well.....the title part with the "autofac" is quite interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new GeneralHtmlNotifier(dataGridView1, checkers));
```